# glpi error connecting to gmail

Tags: gmail, imap

I have installed GLPI 0.90.1 on a CentOS 7.

After more and more problems, everything was going right, but I tried to configure an IMAP mailbox on it in order to create tickets from mail.
The first time I collected my mail (for test), it works well. The ticket is created.

But the second time I tried (maybe 20 minutes later),
I get an error :

```
 "connexion bloked" (translated, because I'm french).
```

I thought it came from Gmail, but the configs were good, and I didn't change anything.

On Glpi, I do not understand my error messages in the .log.

So I come here to find answers.

If you need more informations, tell me.

Comment: How about you provide the error messages in the log?

Comment: from my php-errors.log : "2016-01-11 12:09:18 [2@<server-name>]
  *** PHP Warning(2): imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert/notls}
  Backtrace :
  :                                                  
  inc/mailcollector.class.php:1060                   imap_open()
  inc/mailcollector.class.php:494                    MailCollector->connect()
  front/mailcollector.form.php:80                    MailCollector->collect()"

Comment: please edit your question with all pertinent information.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you must enable [allow less secure apps to access account](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en) on your Gmail account.

Related: [What are the dangers of allowing “less secure apps” to access my Google account?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66025/what-are-the-dangers-of-allowing-less-secure-apps-to-access-my-google-account)

> "less secure apps" refers to applications that send your credentials directly to Gmail